# I am having trouble getting my server action invoked. Getting error: A React form was unexpectedly submitted

Tags: typescript, next.js, react-hook-form, zod, shadcnui

I am trying to build a registration form with Next.js, react-hook-form, and Zod. I have the following code for the form component:

```
'use client';

import { z } from "zod";
import { useRef } from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { useFormState, useFormStatus } from "react-dom";
import { zodResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/zod";
import { registerSchema } from "@/lib/schemas";
import { RegisterProps } from "@/lib/definitions";

function RegisterForm({ onRegister }: RegisterProps) {
  const formRef = useRef<HTMLFormElement>(null);
  const form = useForm<z.infer<typeof registerSchema>>({
    resolver: zodResolver(registerSchema),
    defaultValues: {
      fullName: "",
      email: "",
      password: "",
    },
  });

  const [state, registerAction] = useFormState(onRegister, { message: "" });

  return (
    <Form {...form}>
      <form
        ref={formRef}
        action={registerAction}
        className="space-y-4"
        onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(() => formRef?.current?.submit())}
      >
      ...
     </form>
    </Form>
  );
}
```

My validation works fine, but my action (`registerAction`) never runs. I get the following error when I hit submit on the form:

*Error: A React form was unexpectedly submitted. If you called form.submit() manually, consider using form.requestSubmit() instead. If you're trying to use event.stopPropagation() in a submit event handler, consider also calling event.preventDefault().*

I have tried using the `requestSubmit()` method. The form does not submit, but I don't get the error anymore. I am trying to understand why this happens. Calling the action as in the code snippet below, my action is invoked and the user is registered. Why does the method below work?

```js
const onSubmit = (data: z.infer<typeof registerSchema>) => {
  const formData = new FormData()
  formData.set('fullName', data.fullName;
  formData.set('email', data.email;
  formData.set('password', data.password;

  registerAction(formData)
}

return (
  <Form {...form}>
    <form
      ref={formRef}
      className="space-y-4"
      onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
    >
    ...
    </form>
  </Form>
);
```

Comment: I'm assuming the onSubmit function runs after validation. I am new to using react-hook-form.

Answer (score 0):

`handleSubmit`  will preventDefault  and  receive the form data if form validation is successful. before invoking "onSubmit"

`react-hook-form` give you all this By default
so you don't need ref
you can just pass your server action in `handleSubmit`

```
  <Form {...form}>
    <form
      className="space-y-4"
      onSubmit={form.handleSubmit((values)=> registerAction(values) )}
    >
    ...
    </form>
  </Form>
```

and You can pass an async function and await res from server

```
const onSubmit = async (data) => {
  try {
    const res = await registerAction(values)
    consloe.log(res)
  } catch (e) {
    // handle your error
  }
};

  <Form {...form}>
    <form onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onSubmit(data)} >
    ...
    </form>
  </Form>
```